How to efficiently print a canvas element
I need to allow the user to print a custom layout from a webpage. I'm using a <canvas> element to render the page, and then printing it with window.print() and a CSS @media print rule.
If I leave the canvas at its default size for an 8.5x11 inch piece of paper, the text and images are horribly pixelated. I can fix this by scaling up the canvas resolution by 8x, but this causes the print dialog to take 5+ seconds to load the page for printing.
What could be causing such a massive performance issue? It's obviously being caused by something in the canvas > printer conversion, since the time it takes scales with the number of pixels in the canvas even if all the draw calls in the JS stay the same.
But drawing more elements on the canvas does also causes it to take longer. If it's just a blank page it's relatively fast even at high resolution, but as soon as I add even just a few simple lines or text, it slows down massively.
How can I make the browser print crisp text and images from a canvas without any slowdown?

I suggest sharing a [mcve] so we can see and run your code to repro the issue.
